# $name in the standard values of a template stopped working

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore8.1

I am using sitecore 8.1 and $name token in standard values of a template has stopped working.

I have an article template with title field etc. Title field has standard value with token $name.

When i create a new item using this template, $name is shown in the title field instead of picking and showing the actual item name.

Below are the things i tried:
1. Deleted the existing standard values item and generated fresh.
2. Reset the values on the item.

Did anyone face the same issue ? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Does the problem occur in a clean sitecore Installation?

If so, contact Sitecore Support. If not, please check the sitecore patches used. Sometimes Sitecore Support Patches may cause unexpected errors.

With tokens in sc81 I had only Problems when I created items based on a branchtemplate.

I hope that the approaches help you to locate the cause of the problem.

All best.